# Does 'du' command count the size of unaccessible folders?

Tags: permissions, disk-usage

I am trying to get the size of an user's folder named `allysek` and I am using this command `du -hLlxcs allysek`. I know I don't have permissions to some of the locations.

In the end, I get an output as follows,

```
du: cannot access ‘/export/mite-09/bc/users/allysek/charlet/PS-tools-mjyger/PS-NOVA/IMR90.NOMe-seq.bam’
du: cannot access ‘/export/mite-09/bc/users/allysek/charlet/PS-tools-mfter/PS-NOVA/IMR90.NOMe-seq.bam.bai’
du: cannot access ‘/export/mite-09/bc/users/allysek/charlet/PS-tools-iuhgi/PS-NOVA/colon.WGBS.bam’
du: cannot access ‘/export/mite-09/bc/users/allysek/charlet/PS-tools-kh/PS-NOVA/colon.WGBS.bam.bai’
du: cannot access ‘/export/mite-09/bc/users/allysek/charlet/PS-tools-h/PS-NOVA/dbNOVA_135.hg19.sort.vcf’
du: cannot access ‘/export/mite-09/bc/users/allysek/charlet/PS-tools-master/PS-NOVA/hg19_rCRSchrm.fa’
du: cannot access ‘/export/mite-09/bc/users/allysek/charlet/PS-tools-master/PS-plot/DKO1.NOMe-seq.bam’
du: cannot access ‘/export/mite-09/bc/users/allysek/charlet/PS-tools-master/PS-plot/DKO1.NOMe-seq.bam.bai’
896M    /export/mite-09/bc/users/allysek
896M    total
```

So my question is, does the `896M    total` include sizes of items which I wasn't able to access as well?

Comment: Nope, it only counts the inodes it can read.

Comment: Note: although it wouldn't be a hard thing to implement, there is no way in any unix (or any non-unix) fs to track the size of the files in a directory. Any tool calculating this, has to track the whole directory structure and sum up the found file sizes. If there is no permission to do that, they won't calculate it into the sum (and, as the answers say, you get an error message). There are some pluggable filesystems (for example, reiser4), mainly in experimental phase, they could be easily extended with it, but I never heard it had been done with any of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply not.
Look this example

```
du -shc *
4,0K    AUDIO_TS
4,4G    VIDEO_TS
4,4G    total
chmod 000 * #don't use this in wrong dir!
du -shc *
du: cannot read directory 'VIDEO_TS': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory 'AUDIO_TS': Permission denied
4,0K    AUDIO_TS
4,0K    VIDEO_TS
8,0K    total
```

Answer (score 9):

`du` is an ordinary command running with your privileges and access rights. Just like `ls`. What you can see is what it can see, so it cannot count files that you cannot access.

You can tell it not to complain about files it cannot access by discarding *stderr*:

```
du -hLlxcs allysek 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

No.  Compare the output of

```
du -shc /
```

vs

```
sudo du -shc /
```